# Pandas dataframe replace digits after N decimals to empty string

Tags: python, pandas

I was learning how to using regex in pandas dataframe replace. I encountered the following problem:

I am trying to replace string after N decimal points to empty.
E.g `12.349 ==> 12.35`.

## MWE

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['hello','wold'],
                   'B': [12.346789, 12.223344]})
df1 = df1.astype(str)
round_ = 2
to_replace = r"(^\d+\." + r"\d" * round_ + r")(.*)"
repl = lambda m: m.group(0)

df1 = df1.replace(to_replace,repl,regex=True)
df1
```

Pandas documentation says I can use regex to replace the string, but when I used that I got function repr instead of the value.
How the problem can be solved?

## Update

I was trying to apply format to transpose of dataframe. (Of course I can style before transform, but for some reasons I need to apply format to transpose).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['hello','wold'],
                   'B': [12.349, 12.22]})
df1 = df1.T
df1.style.format({'B': "{:.2f}"}, axis=0)
```

## References

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: @ALollz, Yes I was trying to use `style.format(fmt)` to rows of dataframe, but I could not apply format to rows, only it can be applied to columns. So I tried to first make the dataframe as string type and do the string manipulation to remove extra decimal points.

Comment: I think you want `round(2).astype(str)` instead, no? You can't change `12.349` to `12.35` with regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this pattern:

```
df1 = df1.replace(r"^(\d+\.\d{," + rf"{round_}" + r'})(\d*)',r'\1',regex=True)
```

Output:

```
      survived pclass    age  sibsp  parch    fare
count    891.0  891.0  714.0  891.0  891.0   891.0
mean      0.38   2.30  29.69   0.52   0.38   32.20
std       0.48   0.83  14.52   1.10   0.80   49.69
min        0.0    1.0   0.42    0.0    0.0     0.0
25%        0.0    2.0  20.12    0.0    0.0    7.91
50%        0.0    3.0   28.0    0.0    0.0   14.45
75%        1.0    3.0   38.0    1.0    0.0    31.0
max        1.0    3.0   80.0    8.0    6.0  512.32
```

Comment: Sorry, I just realized it makes `12.349 ==> 12.34` instead of `12.349 ==> 12.35`. I am sorry for XY problem.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to multiply by 100, cast to int and divide by 100:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['hello','wold'],
                   'B': [12.346789, 12.223344]})

df1['B'] = (df1.B * 100).astype(int) / 100

print(df1)
```

prints:

```
       A      B
0  hello  12.34
1   wold  12.22
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need convert `df1.B` to float and use `map` with `f-string`

```
s = df1.B.astype(float).map(lambda x: f'{x:.02f}')

Out[8]:
0    12.35
1    12.22
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are starting with strings, you can convert the column into numbers and use round() to keep only 2 digits.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['hello','wold'],
               'B': ['12.346789', '12.223344']})

df["B"] = round(pd.to_numeric(df["B"]),2)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
A      B
0  hello  12.35
1   wold  12.22
```

If you already have a column of numbers, all you need is this.

```
df["B"] = round(df["B"],2)
```